# how to open the edit screen in calendar for a particular event in android....?

Tags: android, android-calendar

i managed to open `calendar` programmatically. but how can i open `edit event screen` of a calendar programmatically. is it even possible....?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no support in the Android SDK for anything related to the calendar. There is no standard for Intents to open any screens across all of the calendar applications that exist for Android (the AOSP Calendar app, the replacements for that app on various devices, and third-party calendar apps).